# Errores al intentar usar ionic con electron js y capacitor

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, electron, capacitor

intento crear una pequeña app con ionic para practicar y estoy consumiendo una API pública de criptomonedas, peor me genera muchos errores, he intentado con las soluciones que aparecen en algunas preguntas similares pero no me funcionan, 2 de los errores son:

1. "Refused to load the image 'capacitor-electron://-/assets/icon/favicon.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src http: https:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."
2. "Refused to connect to '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive"

he visto que se debe modificar el index.html de la app pero aún así no me funciona.

**Mi index:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ionic App</title>

    <base href="/" />

    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; connect-src * ;"
    />

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
    />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src http: https:;"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:;" />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' https://XXXXX.XXXXXX.com;"
    />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src *;
   img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
   style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *"
    />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

    <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

la secuencia de comandos que he estado utilizando para el proceso es:

```
npm install ngx-electron electron
npm install electron-packager
ionic build
npm i @capacitor-community/electron
npx cap add @capacitor-community/electron
npx cap open @capacitor-community/electron
```